# How to install libavcodec54 in ubuntu vivid?

Tags: 15.04, spotify, libav

Apparently `spotify` needs `libavcodec54` (or 53 or 52) to play local mp3 files. Unfortunately - it doesn't work with `libavcodec56` which is in `Vivid`.

I tried symlinking `libavcodec56` under name of `*54`, but it didn't work.

I also tried to compile from `trusty sources`, but it was failing too.

Is there any place or procedure that I could use to get working `libavcodec54` for `vivid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the neccessary deb files

   ```
   cd
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjpeg/libopenjpeg2_1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavcodec54_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/libavutil52_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install, in the order below

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libopenjpeg2_1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libavutil52_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i libavcodec54_9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
   ```

---

Tested in my Vivid system

```
% lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

% apt-cache policy libopenjpeg2
libopenjpeg2:
  Installed: 1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3+dfsg-4.7ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

% apt-cache policy libavutil52 
libavutil52:
  Installed: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

% apt-cache policy libavcodec54
libavcodec54:
  Installed: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: those packages are not available any longer :(

Answer (score 0):

You can almost certainly just download the .deb file from the earlier version of Ubuntu and install it in parallel with the new one.

I've had to install older libraries in parallel with newer ones a few times for situations like this.

Try installing the deb from here:-
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/libavcodec54/download

You may also need to install some other older libraries as dependencies tho.